# How to Move Site Columns Between Sites

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, migration, column

We have our SharePoint sites in the following tree structure:

```
Corporate
    +--- Division A
         +--- Department 1
         +--- Department 2
         +--- Department 3
    +--- Division B
         +--- Department 1 
         +--- Department 2 
         +--- Department 3
```

I have a number of metadata columns that are defined at the `Division A` level because they're used across all three department sites. Our Corporate Governance team recently chose to prohibit custom columns at the Division level, limiting that customization to the Department level. So I need to move some columns.

Let's say I've got a "NumberOfEmployees" column at the `Division A` level. Right now, I'm thinking that I'll need to do the following:

1. Create three `NumberOfEmployees-Temp` columns; one at each of the
   Department levels.
2. Copy & paste the metadata from `NumberOfEmployees` to `NumberOfEmployees-Temp` in each Department's data.
3. Delete `NumberOfEmployees` from the `Divison A` level.
4. Rename `NumberOfEmployees-Temp` to `NumberOfEmployees` in each of the three
   Departments.

Is there a less painful way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be asking WHY the governance team is restricting custom columns at a given level.

A good process should allow for exceptions when justified.

Otherwise I'd be looking towards a Powershell script to migrate the data to save that manual step at the least.

Comment: I'm asking those same questions, believe you me. I just wish someone would answer. :)